# curl_global_init failed when trying to push to azurestack

Tags: git, azure, azure-stack

I am trying to deploy my flask web app to Azure Stack using "local git repository" method. Unfortunately I encountered this error `fatal: curl_global_init failed` when trying to do push command `git push azurestack master`. I tried to do the `--verbose` option but it still does not output more details on the `curl_global_init` error. Not many information on Google as well.

Anybody can help?